# Cannot create stored procedure. Only one expression can be specified in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure to return specific integer values depending on user login credentials. The following error occurs:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This is my query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Login 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @userName nvarchar(100),
    @password nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF((Select COUNT(*) as Count FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName)=1)
      BEGIN
       IF((SELECT * FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND [Password] = @password)=1)
       -- valid login 
       RETURN 1
       ELSE       
       -- wrong password      
       RETURN 2
      END           
   ELSE
       -- No account associated with the username 
       RETURN 3          
END
GO
```

How can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: You have two selects. Any different approach in one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   IF((SELECT * FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND [Password] = @password)=1)
```

This will not equal 1, it will return all the fields for the row.

Change it to this...

```
   IF((SELECT count(*) FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND [Password] = @password)=1)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. My bad i didn't see this

Comment: @chrisBint Count(*) is taking more time rather than Count(1) why you not use the Count(1) in this query

Comment: @A.Goutam - this has not been true since at least SQL Server 2005 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 0):

Please try and give you feedback

```
IF EXISTS((Select COUNT(1) as Count FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND [Password] = @password)=1)
      BEGIN
       IF((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SimpleSite.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND [Password] = @password)=1)
       -- valid login 
       RETURN 1
       ELSE       
       -- wrong password      
       RETURN 2
      END           
   ELSE
       -- No account associated with the username 
       RETURN 3
```